# Number of ways to traverse a 2D array top left to bottom right

Tags: multidimensional-array, combinations

Came across this question in elements of programming interviews (16.3). I follow the DP solution, but they also give this analytic solution which I do not. The problem statement:

Write a program that counts how many ways you can go from the top-left to the bottom-right in a 2D array.

The analytic solution:

Using the fact that each path from (0, 0) to (n-1, m-1) is a sequence of m-1 horizontal steps and n-1 vertical steps, there must be (n+m-2) Choose (n-1) = (n+m-2)!/((n-1)!(m-1)! such paths.

I get that the equality is just applying the n choose k formula and I see that n+m-2 = (n - 1) + (m - 1). But I don't really know why the number of paths is (n - 1) + (m - 1) Choose (n - 1) to begin with? From the total number of moves we pick a set of vertical ones? Why is that the number of paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each path is comprised of m-1 horizontal steps and n-1 vertical steps, there are in total m+n-2 steps in each path. In order to select a specific path you can define either the vertical or horizontal steps. Let's say you have defined all the vertical steps (i.e. n-1 of them). Once they're defined, there is no actual choice for the rest of the steps (the horizontal ones) - there is only one single possibility for each horizontal step (which makes a connection between the adjacent vertical steps). Therefore, choosing n-1 from m+n-2 defines a single valid path. And the total number of paths will be the number of possibilities to choose n-1 out of m+n-2 (same result can be achieved by choosing m-1 instead of n-1).

See example below:

[image]

Let's say you've chosen the vertical steps (the red ones) - once it's done, there is only one option for each horizontal step (the blue ones). Otherwise, the path will be non-continous and invalid as a result.

Comment: Ah right, by picking one set of steps (either vertical or horizontal), the other becomes fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem statement is not complete the analytic solution works only when in each step you can only go up or right
if we can only go up or right then we need `(n - 1) + (m - 1)` step, to reach the top-left in `(n - 1)` step of these steps we have to go right and in other ones we have to go up
the answer of problem will be `((n + m - 2) choose (n - 1)) or ((n + m - 2) choose (m - 1))`